# Como iterar los links de un menu de navegacion en react

Tags: reactjs, bucle-for, bucles

Buenas tengo un componente navbar y me di cuenta que en vez de escribir 7 etiquetas link podría iterarlos pero no estaría pudiendo desarrollar la lógica, intenté guardar las etiquetas en un array e iterar ese array con un for pero aunque no me da error nose si siquiera se puede hacer eso, aparte de que no funciona..
pero no se me ocurre otra manera, es posible hacer esto? como?

el código:

```
let links = [
<a className='links' href="url">Home</a>,
<a className='links' href="url">we</a>,
<a className='links' href="url">Task</a>,
<a className='links' href="url">Support</a>,
<a className='links' href="url">Others</a>
]

let x;

function desplegarNavbar(){
for (x of links){
document.write(x)
return true
}
}

const Navbar = () => {

return (
<div className="navbar" style ={{color:'white'}}>

{desplegarNavbar}
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React hace fácil iterar desde un array usando el método [map](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

En tu código puedes usar Links directamente en el JSX algo así:

```
const Navbar = () => {

  return (
    <div className="navbar" style ={{color:'white'}}>
        {links.map(elem => 
          elem)}
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Así debería funcionar, saludos!

Comment: Funcionó muchas gracias!